# htaccess not working if put in sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Apache wont load my .htaccess file in my alias directory.

if i put the .htaccess file in my root folder (D:/Development) and project folder (D:/Development/code/project),

`http://localhost/filename.html`
redirects me to stackoverflow.

`http://localhost/project/filename.html`
 returns not found 404.

I'm running xampp on windows 7 64 bit.

Why cant i use my .htaccess in my sub directory?

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/Development">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
 Alias /project "D:/Development/code/project/"
 <Directory "D:/Development/code/project/">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

.htaccess (redirect is for testing):

```
redirect 301 /filename.html http://stackoverflow.com
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(stylesheet|images|favicon) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Is the `index.php` file in your document root or in the `project` directory?

Comment: index.php is in my project directory.
But the problem is, my .htaccess is not loaded in my /project directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have redirect for only the file /filename.html 
Replace First line of your code with

```
redirect 301 filename.html http://stackoverflow.com
```